# Sum multiple column in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I reproduce this query using linq?

```
SELECT 
SUM(SecondsSinceLastEvent) as AccessTime,
SUM (case when DownloadType = 0 then 1 end) FileDownloadCount,
SUM (case when DownloadType = 1 then 1 end) KortextDownloadCount,
SUM (case when Action = 'print' then 1 end) PrintCountFROM EReaderLogs WHERE PublishedContent_Id = XXX
```

Comment: Question is incomplete, What are you grouping upon ? In following case and other cases, `case when Action = 'print' then 1 end`, what's the default value since you need `Sum`, it has to be always a numerical conversion

Answer (score 3):

In LINQ to Entities you need to first use `GroupBy` before using multiple aggregate functions. To sum all the elements in a column you can group by some static key so then a single group would be a whole table:

```
var query = context.EReaderLogs
    .Where(e => e.PublishedContent_Id == someValue)
    .GroupBy(a => 1, (k, g) => 
    {
        AccessTime = g.Sum(e => e.SecondsSinceLastEvent),
        FileDownloadCount = g.Sum(e => e.DownloadType == 0 ? 1 : 0),
        KortextDownloadCount = g.Sum(e => e.DownloadType == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        PrintCount = g.Sum(e => e.Action == "print" ? 1 : 0)
    });
```

Comment: couple of issues here, it should be `e => e.DownloadType == 0 ? 1 : e.DownloadType`, since conversion is only done for 0 value, similar for other cases too, otherwise value remains as expected. Also bring `Where` clause before `GroupBy` for better performance. Also how did you deduce that grouping is on static value and where are you using the array index. Also post grouping `e =>` would be an `IGrouping` type and you can use  `PublishedContent_Id` if it is part of the Key, so this solution will fail

Comment: `context.EReaderLogs` can only be used if its a EF question, which OP hasn't specified

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yes thanks `Where` should be before `GroupBy` that's obvious otherwise I couldn't get `PublishedContent_Id`. In terms of those conditional statements note that OP want's to count sth based on some condition so if a condition is met one is added if not zero so neutral value. I don't see any issue here. `GroupBy(a => 1` is grouping by static value so for each row it's the same. I don't get what do you mean by the array index.

Comment: As per OP case statement, 0 is not a default value, that's why your assumption is incorrect, so it shall be value 1 or actual value not 0

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Why actual value? If there is no `ELSE` statement in `CASE WHEN` null value is returned when condition is not met and not source value. For `SUM` null values are ignored so it's the same as it was zero. `SUM(a.ValueOrNull)` and `SUM(ISNULL(a.ValueOrNull, 0))` return the same result.

Comment: Why `null`, that's your assumption, in fact type is an integer, it may not be nullable type at all. OP doesn't have Null coalesce anywhere in the logic. `DownloadType` is set to a value based on some logic, but if logic doesn't execute then its actual value. You are just running a Linq query over existing data, not assigning any data to default value

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That's not my assumption but specification: "If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL.". Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. In C# and SQL null values are treated differently so e.g. in SQL you can add integer to NULL which returns NULL but SUM is different - it ignores NULLs. The bottom line is that `SUM(CASE WHEN DownloadType = 1 THEN 1 END)` and `SUM(CASE WHEN DownloadType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` (like in my example) give the same result.

Comment: null is not same as 0 in C#, null is undefined, though even when your intention is to get the same Result, but Question is in complete (read my comment on the Question). null is used as placeholder in SQL for query processing, in absence of data, but it is not same as C# null, which means no object allocation. In fact most of the value types will not even accept the null value, until and unless explicitly made nullable type, so chances are when data proceed to C# layer, final result will not match due to assumption that `(Null + Value) in SQL = (0 + Value) in C#`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj But this question is about SQL not C#. Here Linq to Entities provider is used so the only thing that matters is SQL generated from LINQ query. The translated query would give the same result as OPs query. Now you started some off-topic not related to question or my previous comments just repeating what I've just said mostly so I am not going to continue this.

Comment: Your answers are full of assumptions, `Linq to Entities`, `Entity Framework`, no where does OP suggest that. Why not `Linq to Objects`. Where does OP suggest this is generated SQL via EF. In fact OP is just referring to conversion of a SQL query to Linq format

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Not full of assumptions but with the only one assumption that is OP uses Linq to Entities. Question "How can I reproduce this query using linq?" means that OP wants to generate such query using LINQ so Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL are the candidates. It has nothing to do with Linq to Objects but in those provider my query will also work though.